# x server and application clients

Tags: linux, user-interface, unix, xserver, x11

I need some clarifications about the X Server and the applications. As described in the wiki: [X Window System protocols and architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_protocols_and_architecture), "X server is go-between for the user and the client programs, ...,"

My question is, after a Linux PC starts, e.g., CentOS, at beginning, X Server starts to run (taking keyboard, mouse, monitors),

1. does X Server serve I/O for all the subsequent application programs? If not, how to make program A via X Server, while program B not via X Server?
2. what about other GUI programs, e.g. If I have a Qt program, does it also go via x server, like keyboard/monitor <-> X Server <-> Qt? If not, how is this situation handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. Even the console applications will run in a terminal-like application that will be a client of X.
2. Yes. Qt programs do go through X.

Comment: Thank you Didier for your answer. Then, is there any application program which does not go via X server? or else, does X Server take all the I/O? Also, when I develope a GUI application with wxWindows or qt framework, why I did not notice such X Server in the middle? e.g., these framework has some event widgets like MouseClick, so did these event all go via the X-Server? What about the tty or pexpect? And what about the OS I/O? is there any book or resource to explain the relations between X Server and other programs?

Comment: As soon as you want a graphical application, it goes through X. Note that X is very low level compared to wxWidgets or Qt. In X there's no notion of widget. A typical X operation is draw line, or set pixel.

Comment: I see. this is really good information. Do you know if this also apply to all the keyboard and mouse event?

Answer (score 0):

X11 is a system to forward the GUI of a program, it works with every program of a system that supports X11. X11 pretty much forwards to a remote computer all the keys typed and all the clicks done on a computer, sends them to the remote computer and then the remote computer processes the subsequent actions (e.g. make a window appear). To sum up Xserver forwards the screen output of a program (buttons, text boxes etc.) and sends back to the remote machine all the inputs (e.g. clicks, keyboard keys pressed etc.)